# Cakephp 3.0 auth component how to disable hash method

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to add users without hashing password and when I am trying to login without hash it always say invalid username and password is there any setting where I can disable check hash method for login .

Comment: Are you seriously storing passwords in plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Create a password hasher class that does not hash the password. Here is information on how to create and configure custom password hashers:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes

I would suggest to hash your users passwords, though. So stick with the CakePHP default which is the most secure option you have